# What's the best way to convert an IndexSet to an int array?

Tags: swift

I want to convert `NStableView.selectedRowIndexes` to an int array. Is there a fast way to do that? Or should I iterate the IndexSet and push each item to an array?

Comment: `iterate the IndexSet and push each item to an array` that should have you think "I need a `map` operation!"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two simple ways you can do it.

1) Use `map`

`let indexes = tableView.selectedRowIndexes.map({$0})`

2) Pass the `NSIndexSet` into the `Array` initialiser

`let indexes = Array(tableView.selectedRowIndexes)`

Comment: You can omit the brackets in `map({$0})` and just have `map{$0}`. Either way, I would advise against it. `Array(...)` is clearer, and better expresses the intention

Comment: @Alexander I included the parentheses in the example for clarity.

Comment: There's no clarity there. The parenthesises add no new information to improve reading, but they add clutter to detract from it. It could even be `.map({(index: Int) -> Int in return index })`, but it doesn't improve anything

Comment: Sure, but I didn't want OP to wonder why something like this won't compile: `if tableView.selectedRowIndexes.map{$0}.contains(1) {`

Comment: Woah, didn't realize that trailing closures could be an issue, even when they're not at the end of the chain

Comment: The problem is that the Swift compiler can't tell whether `{$0}` is part of the `map` call, or is the actual contents of the `if` block.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of this, but I only thought it happened if the trailing closure was the last thing in the predicate